# Continuity of $f$ on $I$ where $f_n$ is continuous on $I$ and it converges uniformly to $f$ on $I$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=[a,b]$ be a bounded and closed interval, let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions on $I$ and $f:I\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$. $f_n$ is continuous on $I$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$ and it converges uniformly to $f$ on $I$

how can I show that $f$ is continuous on $I$

I'm sorry I don't even know where to start. I have have the definitions of uniform convergence and uniform continuity in front of my but I have no idea how to apply them. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x_o\in I$. For $n>N$ you get
$$
\forall x\in I \ \ |f(x) - f_n(x)| < \frac \epsilon 3
$$
Using the continuity of $f_{N+1}$, for $y\in I\cap [x_0-\eta, x_0 + \eta]$
you have $$
|f_{N+1}(y) - f_{N+1}(x_0)| < \frac \epsilon 3
$$

Then:

$$
|f(y) - f(x_0)| = |f(y) - f_{N+1}(y) + 
f_{N+1}(y) -  f_{N+1}(x_0) +
f_{N+1}(x_0) - f(x_0)|\\
\le |f(y) - f_{N+1}(y)| + 
|f_{N+1}(y) -  f_{N+1}(x_0)| +
|f_{N+1}(x_0) - f(x_0)| \le 3\frac \epsilon 3 = \epsilon
$$